# Spring mvc + hibernate + IN clause from List

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using, in a DaoImplementation an SQL query (cause I could not use HQL or Criteria to find how to solve it).

I have a List object and i need to use the elements of the List as an IN clause in SQL, but i don't know ho to do it...

This is the method in my DAO Implementation

```
public List<Illuminazione> showLightsSituationsByUser(List<Park> parks) {
        Query pianiQuery = getSession().createQuery("from Piano p where p.park = :parks");
        pianiQuery.setParameterList("parks", parks);
        List <Piano> piani = pianiQuery.list();

        Query luciQuery = getSession().createQuery("from Luce l where l.piano in :piani");
        luciQuery.setParameterList("piani", piani);
        List<Luce> luci = luciQuery.list();

        String query = "select i.id_evento, i.id_luce, i.last_date_time, l.numero_luce, l.nome_luce, ill.MaxDate, i.isLit ";
        query += "from illuminazione i inner join  luci l on i.id_luce= l.id_luce and l.id_piano in "+luci+" ";
        query += "inner join (SELECT `id_luce` as numeroLuce2, max(date_time) as MaxDate from illuminazione i2 group by `i2`.`id_luce`) ill ";
        query += "on i.id_luce = ill.`numeroLuce2` and i.`date_time` = ill.MaxDate order by i.`id_luce` asc";
        SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
        q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List<Illuminazione> lista = q.list();

        return lista;
    }
```

from the first 2 queries i get the List i need (*luci*) then from the last query (which is a bit ugly I admit) I have to narrow the results by taking them from the List luci. Obviously, my luci table has a id_piano field.

How can I reach what i need? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, something like this should work:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select i.id_evento ... l.id_piano in (");
    for (Piano piano : piani ){
        sb.append("'");
        sb.append(piani.getId());
        sb.append("', ");
    }
    sb.append(") inner join ...");
    SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery(sb.toString());
```

just make sure you don't include the comma on the last piano, to ensure proper SQL syntax.